# Pie Chart Creation issue

Tags: python, pie-chart

I'm sure I'm being a complete numpty here.  I'm trying to create a couple of pie charts, showing the demographics of respondents to a survey (in this case, Parents or Teachers).  Obviously, at the moment, the columns contain strings, which can't be put into a pie chart.  So I thought I'd do a count of the strings and put that into a variable.  However, when I try to then use that in pie chart, it's failing.

I know this is probably something really simple, and I have Googled around, but I can't seem to find a way to get this working.

Code as follows:

```
respondents_pie=df.groupby('Respondents').size()

print(respondents_pie)
```

Output

Respondents
Parents     31
Teachers    20
dtype: int64

```
fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_axes(0,0,1,1)
ax.axis('equal')
ax.pie(respondents_pie, autopct='%1.2f%%')
plt.show()
```

Error is:  TypeError: from_bounds() argument after * must be an iterable, not int
Error is on line 2 of the code (`ax=fig.add_axes(0,0,1,1)`)
How have I messed this one up?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.  Changing the ax=fig.add_exes(0,0,1,1) to  ax = plt.subplots() resolved the issue.